numba dispatch on type
I would like to dispatch on the type of the second argument in a function in numba and fail in doing so.
If it is an integer then a vector should be returned,
if it is itself an array of integers, then a matrix should be returned.
The first code does not work
@njit
def test_dispatch(X, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, nb.int64):
        ref_pos = np.empty(3, np.float64)
        ref_pos[:] = X[:, indices]
        return ref_pos
    elif isinstance(indices, nb.int64[:]):
        ref_pos = np.empty((3, len(indices)), np.float64)
        ref_pos[:, :] = X[:, indices]
        return ref_pos

while the second one, with an else, does.
@njit
def test_dispatch(X, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, nb.int64):
        ref_pos = np.empty(3, np.float64)
        ref_pos[:] = X[:, indices]
        return ref_pos
    else:
        ref_pos = np.empty((3, len(indices)), np.float64)
        ref_pos[:, :] = X[:, indices]
        return ref_pos

I guess that the problem is the type declaration via nb.int64[:] but I don't get it to work in any other way.
Do you have an idea?
Note that this question applies to numba>=0.59.
generated_jit is deprecated in earlier versions and actually removed from
versions 0.59 on.

You should not use isinstance in a JIT function like this, but instead use @overload (@generated_jit was the old obsolete way to do that) which is specifically made for this purpose. This enables Numba to generate the code faster since only a part of the function is compiled for each case rather than all the case for each specialization. Moreover, isinstance is experimental as specified by Numba in a warning when your first code is executed (warning are reported for users to read them ;) ).

Using the new @overload method
Starting from Numba 0.59, overload must be used instead:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def test_dispatch_scalar(X, indices):
    ref_pos = np.empty(3, np.float64)
    ref_pos[:] = X[:, indices]
    return ref_pos

def test_dispatch_vector(X, indices):
    ref_pos = np.empty((3, len(indices)), np.float64)
    ref_pos[:, :] = X[:, indices]
    return ref_pos

# Pure-python fallback implementation
def test_dispatch_impl(X, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, (int, np.integer)):
        return test_dispatch_scalar(X, indices)
    elif isinstance(indices, np.ndarray) and indices.ndim == 1 and np.issubdtype(indices.dtype, np.integer):
        return test_dispatch_vector(X, indices)
    else:
        assert False # Unsupported

# Numba-specific overload
@nb.extending.overload(test_dispatch_impl)
def test_dispatch_impl_overload(X, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, nb.types.Integer):
        return test_dispatch_scalar
    elif isinstance(indices, nb.types.Array) and indices.ndim == 1 and isinstance(indices.dtype, nb.types.Integer):
        return test_dispatch_vector
    else:
        assert False # Unsupported

@nb.njit
def test_dispatch(X, indices):
    return test_dispatch_impl(X, indices)


Old deprecated solution
Here is an example reasoning about generic types:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.generated_jit(nopython=True)
def test_dispatch(X, indices):
    if isinstance(indices, nb.types.Integer):
        def test_dispatch_scalar(X, indices):
            ref_pos = np.empty(3, np.float64)
            ref_pos[:] = X[:, indices]
            return ref_pos
        return test_dispatch_scalar
    elif isinstance(indices, nb.types.Array) and indices.ndim == 1 and isinstance(indices.dtype, nb.types.Integer):
        def test_dispatch_vector(X, indices):
            ref_pos = np.empty((3, len(indices)), np.float64)
            ref_pos[:, :] = X[:, indices]
            return ref_pos
        return test_dispatch_vector
    else:
        assert False # Unsupported

Here is an example reasoning about specific types:
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.generated_jit(nopython=True)
def test_dispatch(X, indices):
    if indices == nb.types.int64:
        def test_dispatch_scalar(X, indices):
            ref_pos = np.empty(3, np.float64)
            ref_pos[:] = X[:, indices]
            return ref_pos
        return test_dispatch_scalar
    elif isinstance(indices, nb.types.Array) and indices.ndim == 1 and indices.dtype == nb.types.int64:
        def test_dispatch_vector(X, indices):
            ref_pos = np.empty((3, len(indices)), np.float64)
            ref_pos[:, :] = X[:, indices]
            return ref_pos
        return test_dispatch_vector
    else:
        assert False # Unsupported

Requesting specifically 64-bit integers can be a bit too restrictive so I advise you to mix generic type tests and specific ones. For the same reason, you should avoid testing directly if arrays are of a specific type, simply because they can often be contiguous or not or can contain item types compatible with your function.
Note that generic JIT functions are meant to generate functions which are compiled separately regarding the target input type (not the values).

I used generated_jit before.
My question came from users of my library complaining about generated jit being removed from numba.
https://github.com/mcocdawc/chemcoord/issues/76
Hence I wanted to refactor my code using isinstance
https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-generated-jit

The actual code that currently runs fine and has to be rewritten without generated_jit is https://github.com/mcocdawc/chemcoord/blob/master/src/chemcoord/cartesian_coordinates/_cart_transformation.py#L21

Note that in the actual code I use nb.types.Array and nb.types.Integer, but for the purpose of the question I wanted to simplify and requested specifically int64.

You can use extending.overload instead of generated_jit as discussed in this issue

@mcocdawc I did not know about the deprecation. I just follow the instruction in the doc (about using overload) on your own link and it worked well.

Thank you very much for your help so far.
I don't like the new overload syntax because it is super verbose and repetitive. In the same link they also gave a much nicer example that directly used the syntax of my question. They write about it [...] Further, users that are using generated_jit to dispatch on some of the more primitive types may find that Numba’s support for isinstance is sufficient [...] Apparently already just an array of integers is not "primitive" enough anymore.
I will leave the question open just a bit longer, in the hope that one can do without the repetitive syntax.

I agree with you. I changed a bit the implementation to make it less repetitive but it is still a bit and verbose/cumbersome. This is inherently due to the way overload works unfortunately. Sad they made this decision. Here, the isinstance solution can work if Numba would support np.issubdtype but it does not yet :/ . Maybe this one can be replaced so it can be simpler. But then be aware that the same code is replicated for multiple implementation so it is fine for this code but not bigger ones.

Thank you very much! Your refactored code is the best solution I saw regarding the new mechanism of overload. May I perhaps ask if you could change the first sentence of your answer, so that new users are not tricked into believing that generated_jit is still the canonical solution, perhaps you can refer to the Update at the bottom? Then I will of course accept your answer.

Good point. I modified the answer to promote the new @overload solution and explicitly mark the initial one as obsolete.
